# Horizontally Align Text w/ Ellipsis with jQuery button

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, vertical-alignment

I am trying to horizontally align some text (w/ ellipsis) with a jquery button and can't figure out whats going on.

Here is a jsfiddle displaying my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/5bVDu/

```
<span>
    <span id='heading'>Long Heading That Requires Ellipsis</span>
    <span id='hiddenID'>ID</span>
    <button id='closeTab'></button>
</span>
```

As you can see, the button appears to be a little offset (lower) from the text, how can I get them to appear horizontally aligned?

I've tried messing with padding, margin, vertical-align with no success, would really appreciate some help from any of you css gurus out there! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` to `#closeTab`:

```
#closeTab {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    margin-left:5px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5bVDu/2/)**

Comment: ahhh thank you! So i understand what was going on here, the text default was `vertical-align:top`, and the button was default `vertical-align:bottom`...that's why they were originally offset?

Comment: Actually the default vertical-align for non-replaced inline elements is baseline, so you could alternately have specified `vertical-align:top` on `#heading for the same result.` http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5bVDu/9/